# animated text input in a form field for demo

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to create a small web page `onload()` animation that types text in a form field and then presses a button. Kinda like [Let me Google that for you](http://bit.ly/AEC3tS).

Suggestions? I have been searching for a jQuery plugin (preferably) that accomplishes this, or am open to plain JavaScript, but have been coming up empty.

Comment: It would be very simple to use `setTimeout` or `setInteval` to enter the text then dispatch an event to click the button, though the appearance of being clicked would have to be simulated. But you'd likely not actually click the button, instead just set `window.location.href` with an appropriate URL.

Comment: well, there is also the matter of showing the cursor move, and then actually simulating typing the text in the form field

Comment: @punkish: the cursor that you're seeing is actually an image that's being moved with css and javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Pcjua/

the cursor will be just an absolutely positioned PNG image that moves to the box, executes the following code. and after the string is exhausted, move the cursor to the box, then followed by the trigger call in this code.

```
// quick example of searching via google using "http://www.google.com/search?q="

<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" > 
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" />
</form>

​$(document).ready(function() {

    //get element references
    var input = $('input[name="q"]');
    var button = $('input[type="submit"]');
    var form = $('form');

    //the string exploded into single characters
    var query = "Let me Google for you".split('');

    //create function and execute immediately (wrapping of and appending of parenthesis)
    (function autoTypeMe() {

        //get the first letter and append in the input
        var letter = query.shift();
        input[0].value += letter;

        //if string not fully typed, continue
        if (query.length) {
            setTimeout(autoTypeMe, 100);
        } else {

            //move the cursor here

            //trigger the click in two ways, click the button, or submit the form
            button.trigger('click');
            //or
            //form.submit();
        }

    }());

});​
```

Comment: So what does it do that the non-jQuery version doesn't do (other than depend on 4,000 lines of library code)?

Comment: *"Suggestions? I have been searching for a jQuery plugin **(preferably)** that accomplishes this"* - he asked for it. other than `.ready()`, the jQuery to fetch the elements, and `.trigger()` it's still plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval` to add a character from your var to the input every so many milliseconds, then use some jQuery animation APIs to move a PNG of a mouse cursor to the button, and activate the button's onclick.

Comment: lmgtfy does not use flash (I am using a Flash-less Mac, and I can see the animation)

Comment: >.<  yeah... I just caught that :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript `setInterval` to run a function every half second or second. Inside that function you could use something like this psudocode:

```
var count = 0
var string = "Text to go into text field" //first two lines would have to go outside
$(input).val(string.slice(0,count));
count++
```

That should get you started in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple version:

```
<script>

window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.forms.foo;
  var field = form.query;
  var queryText = 'javascript setTimeout';
  var count = 0;

  var fn = function() {
    if (count < queryText.length) {
      field.value = queryText.substring(0, ++count);
      window.setTimeout(fn, 100); 
    } else {
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com.au/#hl=en&q=' + 
                              queryText.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
    }
  }
  fn();
}

</script>
<form name="foo">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="query">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```